# ajax success callback not working within $.each

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an ajax post within an $.each statement and the data is posting correctly to the PHP, but the success callback is not working

below is my jquery. The issue starts below the "//rate videos" comment. Again, all of the data is being sent to PHP properly, just the callback isn't working here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //get user info for header
    $.getJSON('/dev/new/scripts/get_user_info.php', function(user) {
        $(".signout").append('welcome ' + user.first_name + '<br/><a href="/dev/new/scripts/logout.php">SIGN OUT</a>');
        console.log(user);
     });

     //display videos and video ratings
     $.getJSON('/dev/new/scripts/get_vibrary_alleyes.php', function(videos) {
        $.each(videos.vibrary_videos_alleyes, function(name,value) {
            var vibrary_html = '<div class="alleyes-video-row"><div class="video-user"><img src="' + value.profile_url + '" width="77px" height="auto"><br/>' + value.first_name + '</div><div class="alleyes-right"><div class="alleyes-title">' + value.video_title + '</div><div class="alleyes-date">' + value.upload_date + '</div><div class="alleyes-video"><img src="' + value.video_url + '" width="347px" height="auto"></div><div class="alleyes-rate-reply" id="video_' + value.video_id + '"></div></div></div>';
            $(".vibrary-videos").append(vibrary_html);
            if (value.avg_rating <= 0) {
                $("#video_" + value.video_id).append('<div class="alleyes-rating-row"><div class="alleyes-stars"><img class="rate-1-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"><img class="rate-2-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"><img class="rate-3-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"><img class="rate-4-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"><img class="pad-right-10 rate-5-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"></div>Rate this video</div><div class="alleyes-reply-row"><img src="/dev/new/images/reply_video_icon.png" class="pad-right-10">Reply by video</div>');
            }
            if (value.avg_rating > 0 && value.avg_rating < 1.5) {
                $("#video_" + value.video_id).append('<div class="alleyes-rating-row"><div class="alleyes-stars"><img class="rate-1-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-2-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"><img class="rate-3-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"><img class="rate-4-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"><img class="pad-right-10 rate-5-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"></div>Rate this video</div><div class="alleyes-reply-row"><img src="/dev/new/images/reply_video_icon.png" class="pad-right-10">Reply by video</div>');
            }
            if (value.avg_rating >= 1.5 && value.avg_rating < 2.5) {
                $("#video_" + value.video_id).append('<div class="alleyes-rating-row"><div class="alleyes-stars"><img class="rate-1-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-2-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-3-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"><img class="rate-4-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"><img class="pad-right-10 rate-5-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"></div>Rate this video</div><div class="alleyes-reply-row"><img src="/dev/new/images/reply_video_icon.png" class="pad-right-10">Reply by video</div>');
            }
            if (value.avg_rating >= 2.5 && value.avg_rating < 3.5) {
                $("#video_" + value.video_id).append('<div class="alleyes-rating-row"><div class="alleyes-stars"><img class="rate-1-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-2-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-3-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-4-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"><img class="pad-right-10 rate-5-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"></div>Rate this video</div><div class="alleyes-reply-row"><img src="/dev/new/images/reply_video_icon.png" class="pad-right-10">Reply by video</div>');
            }
            if (value.avg_rating >= 3.5 && value.avg_rating < 4.5) {
                $("#video_" + value.video_id).append('<div class="alleyes-rating-row"><div class="alleyes-stars"><img class="rate-1-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-2-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-3-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-4-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="pad-right-10 rate-5-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_g.png"></div>Rate this video</div><div class="alleyes-reply-row"><img src="/dev/new/images/reply_video_icon.png" class="pad-right-10">Reply by video</div>');
            }
            if (value.avg_rating >= 4.5) {
                $("#video_" + value.video_id).append('<div class="alleyes-rating-row"><div class="alleyes-stars"><img class="rate-1-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-2-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-3-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="rate-4-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"><img class="pad-right-10 rate-5-' + value.video_id + '" src="/dev/new/images/rate_y.png"></div>Rate this video</div><div class="alleyes-reply-row"><img src="/dev/new/images/reply_video_icon.png" class="pad-right-10">Reply by video</div>');
            }

            //rate videos
            $(document).on('click', ".rate-1-" + value.video_id, function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/dev/new/scripts/rate_video.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {video_id:value.video_id,rating:1},
                    success: function () {
                        alert('sdfdas');
                    }
                });

            });
            $(document).on('click', ".rate-2-" + value.video_id, function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/dev/new/scripts/rate_video.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {video_id:value.video_id,rating:2},
                    success: function () {
                        alert('sdfdas');
                    }
                });

            });
            $(document).on('click', ".rate-3-" + value.video_id, function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/dev/new/scripts/rate_video.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {video_id:value.video_id,rating:3},
                    success: function () {
                        alert('sdfdas');
                    }
                });

            });
            $(document).on('click', ".rate-4-" + value.video_id, function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/dev/new/scripts/rate_video.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {video_id:value.video_id,rating:4},
                    success: function () {
                        alert('sdfdas');
                    }
                });

            });
            $(document).on('click', ".rate-5-" + value.video_id, function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/dev/new/scripts/rate_video.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {video_id:value.video_id,rating:5},
                    success: function () {
                        alert('sdfdas');
                    }
                });

            });

        });
        console.log(videos);
     });

});
```

Comment: Anytime an ajax call is not being successful, you should install an error handler on the ajax call and look at the error.  Can often also see what's going on by looking at the network tab to see what goes over the network in the chrome debugger.

Comment: you can add `error: function(a,b,c) {alert(c);}` after your success functions to alert you to potential errors.  Also if you are returning data from your ajax calls your `success: function()` will need to have a parameter.

Comment: You may find the syntax in the last example on the jQuery reference's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) page helpful in tracing ajax errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$(document).on('click', ".rate-1-" + value.video_id, function() {
    // ...
});
```

If you're using a jQuery version below 1.7, you'll want to use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead.

Comment: hmm...see what you're getting at here, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: are you using jquery v1.7+?

Comment: have you tried my solution with an `alert('asdf')` instead of the ajax call?

Comment: updated my code to show what i'm trying here. The alert displays outside of the ajax call, but still nothing inside the success callback

Comment: then it seems like your ajax call may be incorrect. can you debug further using Firebug or similar?

Comment: haha that's what's most frustrating is that firebug is showing no errors or warnings

Comment: well, when I do error: alert..., it does the alert, so clearly something's wrong with the ajax...it's strange that it's being sent properly to the PHP though

Comment: well it must be that the ajax request is not succeeding.. at least you have a lead now

Comment: Got it - I used your method and in my php I added: echo json_encode(array("status" => "success")) and that seemed to do it. I guess I just needed to send something back from the php